# Master Detail - How to save state before save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm programing a new system in Asp.Net MVC 5 with EF6, i have a problem when i try to implement a master - detail form, like head and lines of a ticket. 
What is the right way to save the lines inserted before save in the database? When do the final post to save the ticket, how i can get the lines inserted?

Answer (score 1):

In EF as long as you have the `Lines` as part of your `Head`

E.g.

```
public class Head
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

As long as the `Lines` property have all the lines you need to save, EF will handle saving the `Head` first, and than saving each line with the correct head ID, all in one transaction.